# Last displayed glossary entry's hanging indentation gets lost with index style

Tags: indentation, glossaries

I'm using the `glossaries` package in a document and use the `index` style with it (because I need optional symbols to be displayed in the glossary).

The weird thing is that the last displayed item's hanging indentation gets lost.

Here's a minimal example with only two items. What do I miss?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossary

\newglossaryentry{GLO1}{name={GLO1},text={Glossary Entry 1},description={Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. }}

\newglossaryentry{GLO2}{name={GLO2},text={Glossary Entry 2},description={Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text }}

\begin{document}

\gls{GLO1}
\gls{GLO2}

\printglossary[style=index]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm using a quite recently installed (stable) texlive 2013 and compile with pdflatex and makeglossaries.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is seems to be a bug in the definition of the `index` style.  The style defines `theglossary` environment to end with no special commands, what is needed is a `\par`.  You can fix this by renewing the index style in your document.  Below I have just copied the definition from `glossary-tree.sty` where it resides, replaced `\newglossary` with `\renewglossary` and fixed the ending command.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\renewglossarystyle{index}{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.3pt}%
     \let\item\@idxitem}%
    {\par}%            %%%%%% Addition here
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
\item\glsentryitem{##1}\textbf{\glstarget{##1}{##2}}%
  \ifx\relax##4\relax
  \else
    \space(##4)%
  \fi
  \space ##3\glspostdescription \space ##5}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
    \ifcase##1\relax
      % level 0
      \item
    \or
      % level 1
      \subitem
      \glssubentryitem{##2}%
    \else
      % all other levels
      \subsubitem
    \fi
    \textbf{\glstarget{##2}{##3}}%
    \ifx\relax##5\relax
    \else
      \space(##5)%
    \fi
    \space##4\glspostdescription\space ##6}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\ifglsnogroupskip\else\indexspace\fi}}
\makeatother

\makeglossary

\newglossaryentry{GLO1}{name={GLO1},text={Glossary Entry 1},description={Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. }}

\newglossaryentry{GLO2}{name={GLO2},text={Glossary Entry 2},description={Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text }}

\newglossaryentry{GLO3}{name={GLO3},text={Glossary Entry 3},description={Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text. Some other text }}

\begin{document}

\gls{GLO1}
\gls{GLO2}
\gls{GLO3}

\printglossary[style=index]

\end{document}
```